# Why I keep getting ECONNRESET error on proxy calls in MAC OSX only, totally arbitrary with some successful calls (Pretty desperate)

Tags: node.js, angular

Dev team is running the same code, They use UNIX machines I use MAC.
We have a maven project API is separated from front- end Angular. Angular makes proxy calls to the API in dev mode.

I am getting ECONNRESET errors and can not save or load certain results. Pretty arbitrary as most of them resolves ok.

I tried every trick people suggested so far on the proxy setup by using * or using IP rather than localhost name etc. Three must be something related to MAC OS. Here is the proxy set up code in proxy.config

```
{
  "/emport-api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8080",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Here is the part in package.json

```
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --extract-css=true",
    "build": "ng build --prod --progress export.modal.component.ts --output-path dist",
    "test": "jest",
    "codecoverage": "jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "fixlinting": "ng lint --fix",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

This is one of the errors

```
[HPM] GET /emport-api/rest/user/accessControl -> http://localhost:8080
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /emport-api/rest/user/accessControl from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNRESET)
```

Let me now if I need to put certain info here to have the problem explained better.

Comment: in which context is localhost:4200 making a request? from a browser if so which browser?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure, I mean they are rest calls, the call is made inside angular running at localhost:4200 rest api is running at localhost:8080 translation should happen inside javascript.

Comment: the page does not load because of this, or the values are not written to database and I get error... and this happens in any browser. Safari and Chrome particularly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the fix for this after trying all other methods including giving a timeout duration, only keep connection alive option solved it for me.

Added

```
"headers": {
  "Connection": "keep-alive"
 }
```

to the api object